# Git bash not activating base by default when I open

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I used this [link](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/setting-up-conda-in-git-bash/534473) to enable conda in my git bash in my Windows setup

However, whenever I open git bash from the context menu, it does not activate the base environment by default. How do I get it to activate base by default whenever I open the bash terminal in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Add conda activate at the end of `.bashrc` file so that it becomes as follows:

```
. /c/Users/DEADARA/Miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate
```